# How to get time when object (person) detected in video python

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection, face-recognition

im about to build video analytic using python. im able to detect person in video using tensorflow.
i can detect the person who appear in the video and save the person image (save the object detected). But i cannot get the time when the person appear in video. i have scenario like this :

- i have 16 seconds video from security camera.
- in the 5th second, someone appears on the video

so it will print
"Person detected at 00:00:05"

here is some of my code for detection :

```
while(cap.isOpened()):
            ret, frame = cap.read()        
            frame_count += 1
            millis = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)

            if not  ret:
                print("end of the video file...")
                break
            
            input_frame = frame

            # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
            image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(input_frame, axis=0)

            # Actual detection.
            (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
                [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
                feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})

            # insert information text to video frame
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

            # Visualization of the results of a detection.        
            counter, csv_line, counting_mode = vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(cap.get(1),
                                                                                                  input_frame,
                                                                                                  1,
                                                                                                  is_color_recognition_enabled,
                                                                                                  np.squeeze(boxes),
                                                                                                  np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
                                                                                                  np.squeeze(scores),
                                                                                                  category_index,
                                                                                                  targeted_objects=targeted_object,
                                                                                                  use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                                                                                                  line_thickness=4)
            if(len(counting_mode) == 0):
                cv2.putText(input_frame, "...", (10, 35), font, 0.8, (0,255,255),2,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX)                       
            else:
                counting_mode = "{} {}".format(counting_mode, millis) 
                cv2.putText(input_frame, counting_mode, (10, 35), font, 0.8, (0,255,255),2,cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX)
                
            cv2.imshow('object counting',input_frame)

            if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                    break

        cap.release()
```

im looking in google and most of them said to use `cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC` but im struggle to use it. it only shows in miliseconds.

thank you in advance for helping.

> EDIT

what im asking is how to get the time when person appear (detected) in the video. like im my scenario, on the 5th second the person detected so it will print "Person detected at 00:00:05"

Comment: Milliseconds are easy to convert to seconds. It's `milliseconds / 1000`.

Comment: hi @CoderCharmander thank you for your answer, what i mean is how to get the time when person appear or detected in that video.

Comment: `if len(boxes)>0: print("Person detected at", millis/1000)`

Answer (score 1):

If you can get the timestamps in milliseconds you can use datetime.timedelta to get a more human readable timestamp

```py
from datetime import timedelta

my_milliseconds = [54321, 7562732, 1234, 24984, 349589]

for millisecs in my_milliseconds:
    timestamp = timedelta(milliseconds=millisecs)
    print(timestamp)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
0:00:54.321000
2:06:02.732000
0:00:01.234000
0:00:24.984000
0:05:49.589000
```